# In angular smart table how to disable EDIT functionality for one row

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular smart table.I am displaying JSON data in table using ng-repeat.All rows are editable.But I want to disable edit functionality for on row.One row should be read only. 
In my html table 22 record displayed from JSON.All rows are editable.How disable edit button(also save and cancel) for first row.

Comment: Can you post your code and your try?

Comment: I have posted my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$index`, `$first`, `$middle`, `$last`, `$even`, `$odd` of `ngRepeat` statement for specific rows.

Here i recommend to use `$first`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary editable-table-button btn-xs" ng-click="rowform.$show()" ng-disabled="$first">
    Edit
</button>
```

see this sample demo here.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [{
      name: 'John',
      age: 25,
      gender: 'boy'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jessie',
      age: 30,
      gender: 'girl'
    },
    {
      name: 'Johanna',
      age: 28,
      gender: 'girl'
    },
    {
      name: 'Joy',
      age: 15,
      gender: 'girl'
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      <td>
        {{$index}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-disabled="$first">test</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I want this for edit button.I tried same.save button get disabled.

Comment: @Ashish they are the same. anyway i changed the sample code block for you(from save button to edit button)

Comment: Solved.Thank you.

Comment: @Ashish if the answer ever helped, marker it as an answer plz.